# How to have individual .idea folders on a shared project

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

We have multiple developers working on a shared project through dropbox. Each time one of the developers saves a file, the other developers get the following message:

"Project Files Changed

Project components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:

ToolWindowManager

Would you like to reload project?"

How can each person have their own settings in a shared project so this is not a problem?

Comment: Use version control instead of dropbox. Or you can create a new project in a directory outside of dropbox and when configuring a module specify the dropbox project directory as the content root (module file location should be customized to be outside of the module root directory). This way your IDE files will be outside of dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should use VCS (Version control systems) as for example git, and ignore the IDE configuration files ([`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)), so you can avoid the conflicts with the configuration files

Comment: Is this being caused by the IDE's own version control? I have no problem doing away with that entirely if possible

Comment: @sublimesummer IDE saves workspace very often, at very least after each  significant operation. Because you are accessing whole project (code + project settings, which is stored in `.idea` subfolder) IDE detects such changes in project config (which is important for self-functioning) and informs you about it. So you either use VCS for whole thing (so all of you work on own copy of the project and then nicely merge it when needed) .. or at very least keep project settings outside of the project as CrazyCoder said  (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170102 has instructions on how to)

Comment: @sublimesummer In general, Dropbox-alike sharing is OK if it's only one dev working with the code at a time (e.g. you at one place (work) and then later from another place (home)). But for multiple simultaneous sessions -- not great -- VCS usage is MUCH better/safer in general.